# Excel VBA Macro Compile error: Expected End Sub

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to assign my code to a button which works stand-alone in VBA however but I'm receiving the following error when adding it to a button;

> Compile error: Expected End Sub

My code is as follows;

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Private Sub filename_cellvalue()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim filename As String
    Path = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\Invoices\"
    filename = Range("K13")
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=Path & filename & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

VBA is new to me so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you indent your code properly you see that your first procedure `Sub Button1_Click()` has no `End Sub`. That is what the error message tells you.

Answer (score 4):

You're declaring a procedure twice: `Sub Button1_Click()`  and `Sub filename_cellvalue()`.

You should delete one. If you're putting the code in your button event, delete  `Sub filename_cellvalue()`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Sub Button1_Click()
>
> Private Sub filename_cellvalue()
> ```

`Sub` statements declare a procedure scope. The syntax goes:

```
{accessibility} Sub {name} ({args})
    {statements}
End Sub
```

Where the `{accessibility}` modifier, `{args}` parameter list, and `{statements}` in the body, are optional (note, without an access modifier, a procedure is implicitly `Public` - whereas in many other languages [including VB.NET] the implicit default is `Private`; best be explicit here).

Such a syntax makes *nested* `Sub` statements illegal:

```
Sub DoSomething()
    Sub Illegal()
    End Sub
End Sub
```

Therefore, when the compiler encounters a `Sub` statement, everything that follows is considered as part of the procedure's body, up to the next `End Sub` token.

If the `Button1_Click` handler is legitimate, it needs to be properly terminated *before* `Sub filename_cellvalue` begins:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub filename_cellvalue()
    '...
End Sub
```

Otherwise, the `Sub Button1_Click()` incomplete statement needs to be removed.

That said, `filename_cellvalue` is a bad identifier for a procedure: `Sub` procedures *do something*, their names should start with a verb. `ExportAsPDF` would be more appropriate, for example. Note the `PascalCase` name, as opposed to `lower_snake_case`: the underscore character has a special meaning in VBA, as evidenced by `Button1_Click`.

The underscore separates the interface/event source from the interface member/event name: `Button1_Click` is invoked when the `Button1` object raises its `Click` event, and naming that procedure anything different would break the link between the object and the event handler: the procedure would never run in response to a `Click` on `Button1`. Using underscore in non-handler procedures, especially if public, *will* cause problems (read: more compile errors) when you get into more advanced, object-oriented programming concepts involving interfaces and polymorphism.